# Grok classifier for parquet

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

Is it possible to create a grok classifier for Parquet files? If so, where can I find examples?

I'm using AWS Glue Catalog and I'm trying to create external tables on top of Parquet files. I'd like the classifier to split the files according to one of the column of the files.

All my files have the column "table" and all records in a file have the same table.

My S3 structure is like this

```
- s3://my-bucket/my-prefix/table1/...
- s3://my-bucket/my-prefix/table2/...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, classifier is not used for conditional parsing of data and moving to different tables.

You may write lambda/ecs/glue-job (depending on processing time) which will take these files and move to table wise folders in s3 bucket. e.g. s3-data-lake/ingestion/table1, s3-data-lake/ingestion/table2 and so on. Then you can run crawler over s3-data-lake/ingestion/ which will create all glue tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have the structure you said: s3-data-lake/ingestion/table1, s3-data-lake/ingestion/table2. But since the structure of the data is similar glue crawler only gives one table as output. I'll edit the question to add the structure of the data.

Comment: aaha! In crawler, Uncheck checkbox:  _italic_Grouping behavior for S3 data (optional->Create a single schema for each S3 path_italic_ and run it

It should create table for each S3 path